# Numpy and memory allocation on Mac OS X vs. Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos, numpy, ubuntu-16.04

I use numpy to load a large matrix using 64bit Python.

It works fine on Macbook Pro with 8GB memory.

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
>>> mb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
>>> matrix = mb.fit_transform(questions_topics)
>>> sys.getsizeof(matrix) 
47975472376
>>> matrix.shape
(2999967, 1999)
```

But it raises `MemoryError` on Ubuntu Google VM instance with 16GB memory and 10GB swap.

```
>>> y = mb.fit_transform(questions_topics)
/home/Liwink/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in _process_toarray_args(self, order, out)
1037             return out
1038         else:
-> 1039             return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
1040
1041     def __numpy_ufunc__(self, func, method, pos, inputs, **kwargs):
MemoryError:
```

When the matrix is loaded on Mac OS, it takes 50G VIRT.
[image]

I have two questions:

1. Where is the matrix(about 50GB) kept, in memory or disk?
2. How can I load this matrix on VM?

Comment: You are going to have to give more details. But by chance is the VM Python a 32bit version? Because that will be the fundamental limit of your address space, no matter how much RAM that machine has.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. Python is 64bit version. What kinds of some key information should I provide?

Comment: could you make the example self-contained by just allocating an array rather than using some learn-functions on an unknown quantity `questions_topics`. That would be really helpful :)

Comment: So clearly even with your swap you don't have enough memory. You can always add swap-space if you have the disk space for it on the VM.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But for Mac OS, it does not have enough swap as well.

Comment: Yes, you can read about [virtual memory here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/AboutMemory.html). It is similar to swap, in that it is stored on disk.

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks for your suggestion, I have updated it.

Comment: `np.zeros` is tricky ... could you try `np.full`?

Comment: @MSeifert they are using a `sklearn` estimator. The problem is that it is returning a `np.int64` array, but there isn't enough memory.

Comment: The question is if it's an uninitialized array or an initialized one.

Comment: @MSeifert the error message indicates that the `MultiLabelBinarizer` is trying to use `np.zeros`. Check the edit log.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks a lot. I solved my problem temporarily by increasing the swap to 50GB on VM. But I am still confused about the virt and swap and it seems like that they work differently on Mac OS and Linux.

Comment: @liuyihe they are similar approaches to memory management just implemented differently.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But `np.zeros` may return an un-initialized array (depending on the system), so it could just be that the first system just returns a "promise to allocate the required memory - if needed".

Comment: @MSeifert well, whatever is happening, on MacOS it just used 50gigs of virtual memory to output the fully materialized array. You can see the output.... in Ubuntu it errored out at some point before the array was fully allocated, and it would have failed anyway with only 26 gigs of combined RAM+swap. I'll defer to any systems people's knowledge on the intricacies of the matter...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga On Ubuntu, it uses up the memory first, but on Mac OS it "saves" memory. 
On Ubuntu:
VIRT: 49.7G; RES: 14.2G.


On Mac OS:
VIRT: 50.0G; RES: 2114M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, I solved the problem by [increasing the swap](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04).

But it is still not perfect, since on Ubuntu it will use up the memory first but on Mac OS it "saves" memory a lot.

On Ubuntu:
[image]

On Mac OS:
[image]

On Ubuntu, it uses much more RES than it on Mac OS.

How can I save the memory on Ubuntu?