# MemoryError when concatenate lists on Ubuntu but not Mac

Tags: python, macos, numpy, ubuntu

```
 #pseudo, actual list file could be found in the link below
 data_words = [[word_11, word_12,...,word_1n],   
              [word_21],word_22,...,word_2m],
               ...  
              ]
 import pickle
 with open('data_words.pk', 'rb') as f:
     data_words = pickle.load(f)
 word_list = np.concatenate(data_words)
 >>MemoryError on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64 bit with 16G memory, Virtual Machine(VMware)
 >>No problem on MacOS 10.12.6 with 8G memory

 #And the code below works fine for both Mac and Ubuntu
 import itertools
 word_list_flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data_words))
```

Since `data_words` list is less than 400Mb, so  maybe there is something wrong with `numpy.concatenate()` in Ubuntu 18? I'd really like to know why this kind of behavior happens, although I get desirable results by using 
[CTT's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

Here is the [data_words](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3fjnokdw9k5kmw/data_words.pk.zip?dl=0) list I used to produce the Error

Comment: Are you running the same versions of Python on both machines?

Comment: @Selcuk yes. Both python 3.6.5(in anaconda3) and same numpy version.

Comment: Strange. Have a look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027749/numpy-and-memory-allocation-on-mac-os-x-vs-linux)

Comment: @Selcuk I also monitored my memory usage on Ubuntu when I ran the python script, it never uses over 5g memory . And in order to make sure my python installation can use as many  memory as the machine have, I deliberately ran some codes to use about 14G memory.